# How to set the value into an array from a function? In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to set the value of an array from a function?
The issue is because I've to change the value of the index before of be set with an variable value.

```
function foo(arr) {
    this.arr=arr;
}

var f = new foo(['a', 'b', 'c']);

// I had thinked in use a function like this one
// Note thta I used index to pass an array wich could
// be greater than 1 dimension.

foo.prototype.setv = function(index, v) {
    this.arr.index = v;
}

// but it does not works like I was expecting
idx = [1];
foo.setv(idx, "Z");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
this.arr.index = v;
```

Should be this:

```
this.arr[index] = v;
```

In your code you are setting a property of the array, named "index" to a value. This does not actually use the `index` argument passed to your setter function. Using the braket notation for setting allows you to use the `index` argument as an actual index for the array.

But also, your expected usage is strange:

```
idx = [1];
foo.setv(idx, "Z");
```

Why is `idx` an array? If you want to set a specific index of the internal array to a value, you would expect to pass in just the index. So that would make more sense to be simply:

```
idx = 1;
foo.setv(idx, "Z");
```

Comment: Thanks. IMHO, all Stack Overflow answers should include the _why_, as well as the how.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.prototype.setv = function(index, v) {
    this.arr[index] = v;
}

idx = 1;
foo.setv(idx, "Z");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.prototype.setv = function(index, v) {
    this.arr[index[0]]= v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few mistakes in the code you've posted:

```
// capitalizing "constructors" is a good standard to follow
function Foo(arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
}

var f = new Foo(['a', 'b', 'c']);

Foo.prototype.setv = function(index, v) {
    // you access array indices via arr[index], not arr.index
    this.arr[index] = v;
}

// idx should be a number, not an array
idx = 1;

// you call the prototype function on the new'd object, not the "class"
f.setv(idx, "Z");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mB28/